# Variable in memory not updated by a store to that symbol

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086, memory-segmentation

When I run the emu8086, this result(ans) return to me 0 ..Why ?

```
data segment
ans dw ? 
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
mov ax,@data
mov dx,ax
mov ax,2
mov bl,2
mul bl
mov ans,ax
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h  
ends
end start
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> mov ax,@data
> mov dx,ax
> ```

This part of the code must setup the `DS` segment register.
You made a typo and wrote `DX` instead!

```
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
```

Because of this error, the result of your `AL` * `BL` multiplication (4) was still written in memory by `mov ans,ax` but it didn't make it to the *data segment*. It overwrote the first word of the ProgramSegmentPrefix because that was where `DS` was pointing at.